# Eclipse: Create Runnable .jar WITH manifest possible?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, manifest

Eclipse allows you to build a runnable .jar, but does not allow you to specify a manifest.mf.

Alternatively, you can create a .jar, and specify a manifest, but it will not be runnable.

How do I build a runnable .jar WITH a manifest.  I want to do this so I can have a splash screen.

Edit: The Eclipse jar export options are limited.  The real problem I was having was the exported jar, while it specified Main-Class, did not include libraries.  **To export a jar with a manifest AND libraries, install the Fatjar plugin.  http://fjep.sourceforge.net/**

Eclipse's built-in "runnable jar export" will include libraries, but not allow one to specify the manifest.  And the "export jar" allows one to specify a manifest, but will not package libraries into the jar.  Fatjar allows you to do both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the normal export will generate a runnable jar as long as the manifest you give it specifies the `Main-Class:` configuration.

Comment: I have been trying this, but can't get the .jar to execute.  In the dialog, it asks to browse the the main class name, and it writes this attribute into the .mf, which is also exported with the jar, but for some reason it wont run...

Comment: You may have a different issue entirely, try running it from a commandline with `java -jar yourjar.jar`.  You could be getting some classpath error that shows up in stdout but it appears/disappears too quickly to read when run from a double click.